# Why are my cache fragments not storing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, fragment

In one of my views, I have:

```
- cache("crumb") do
  %ul.breadcrumb
```

In the browser, the view loads and you see the breadcrumbs.

In `development.rb`, I have:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store                       = :dalli_store
```

After loading the view, why do I then have:

```
ActionController::Base.new.read_fragment("crumb")
Cache read: views/crumb
D, [2016-01-14T12:14:12.707228 #2465] DEBUG – : Cache read: views/crumb
Read fragment views/crumb (0.5ms)
I, [2016-01-14T12:14:12.707727 #2465]  INFO – : Read fragment views/crumb (0.5ms)
=> nil
```

The cache is readable and writable from the command line:

```
ActionController::Base.new.write_fragment("crumb", "foo")
Cache write: views/crumb
D, [2016-01-14T12:14:29.401736 #2465] DEBUG – : Cache write: views/crumb
Write fragment views/crumb (1.2ms)
I, [2016-01-14T12:14:29.402987 #2465]  INFO – : Write fragment views/crumb (1.2ms)
=> "foo"
[4] pry(main)> ActionController::Base.new.read_fragment("crumb")
Cache read: views/crumb
D, [2016-01-14T12:14:33.990289 #2465] DEBUG – : Cache read: views/crumb
Read fragment views/crumb (0.6ms)
I, [2016-01-14T12:14:33.990858 #2465]  INFO – : Read fragment views/crumb (0.6ms)
=> "foo"
```

But even after I write to the cache at the command line in this way, I see my view's HTML, not "foo", in the browser when I reload the page.

Note: I will include model objects in the key once I get this working. But I've deliberately simplified the test case for the purposes of this post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that caching actually was working, but to test it in the console you need to include the cache digest that Rails attaches automatically. You can copy-paste this digest from the log. You end up typing something like `Rails.cache.read("views/crumb/etcetc...")`/